# Versioning file server

Tags: filesystems, file-sharing, version-control

Looking for a virtual filesystem server (like ftp or sshd or NFS, samba) with the following features:

- open-source
- cross platform server (Linux/Windows/OSX)
- *linear* file versioning (don't need to have branches) - but done **transparently**, simple, on the save create a new version
- ability access to the earlier version with some file-name-semantic (like file.jpg;ver:3 or so)
- support for some level of ACL / permissions

Exists something like?

Answer (score 1):

I think [WebDAV](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/WebDAV) fits the description. Just not sure about [the ACLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5397) here. This may require some additional effort from the web server.